# Plotting pandas Series line becomes curved

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, time-series

The problem is to plot a straight line with uneven distribution of dates. Using the series values data fixes the curviness problem, but loses the timeline (the dates). Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: Why aren't the dates mapped straight to ticks on x axis:

```
0 -> 2017-02-17,
1 -> 2017-02-20,
... ?
```

Now there seems to be 12 ticks for the orange line but only 8 datapoints.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def straight_line(index):  
  y = [3 + 2*x for x in range(len(index))] 
  zserie = pd.Series(y, index=index)

  return zserie

if __name__ == '__main__':

  start = '2017-02-10'
  end = '2017-02-17'
  index = pd.date_range(start,end)

  index1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2017-02-17', '2017-02-20', '2017-02-21', '2017-02-22',
               '2017-02-23', '2017-02-24', '2017-02-27', '2017-02-28',],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='pvm', freq=None)   

  plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 4))  

  zs = straight_line(index)
  zs.plot()

  zs = straight_line(index1)
  zs.plot()

  plt.figure(2, figsize=(8, 4))  

  zs = straight_line(index1) 
  plt.plot(zs.values)
```

[image: Curvy line example]
[image: Straight line with zs.values]

Comment: Are you trying to create a straight line with uneven spacing of the date (x-axis) or are you trying to make the date values act like a categorical value?

Comment: The orange line in the first plot seems to be exactly the plot you are looking for. What is wrong with it?

Comment: To get a straight line you'd have to adjust the x-axis to be adjusted at the same rate the y-axis is. Which doesn't really work for plotting against dates of varying distance from each other. Why do you need the graph to be in a straight line for the data?

Comment: Oh, I should have explained that the original problem is a common task of plotting a timeserie with its regression line into same figure, with dates. A regression line should be straight.

Comment: Why aren't the dates mapped straight to datapoints, like:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph is treating the dates correctly as a continuous variable. The days of `index_1` *should* be plotted at x coordinates of 17, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 27, and 28. So, the graph with the orange line is correct.

The problem is with the way you calculate the y-values in the `straight_line()` function. You are treating the dates as if they are just categorical values and ignoring the gaps between the dates. A linear regression calculation won't do this--it will treat the dates as continuous values.

To get a straight line in your example code you should convert the values in `index_1` from absolute dates to relative differences by using `td = (index - index[0])` (which returns a pandas [TimedeltaIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.html)) and then use the days from `td` for the x-values of your calculation. I've shown how you can do this in the `reg_line()` function below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def reg_line(index):
    td = (index - index[0]).days  #array containing the number of days since the first day
    y = 3 + 2*td
    zserie = pd.Series(y, index=index)
    return zserie

if __name__ == '__main__':

  start = '2017-02-10'
  end = '2017-02-17'
  index = pd.date_range(start,end)

  index1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2017-02-17', '2017-02-20', '2017-02-21', '2017-02-22',
               '2017-02-23', '2017-02-24', '2017-02-27', '2017-02-28',],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='pvm', freq=None)   

  plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 4))  

  zs = reg_line(index)
  zs.plot(style=['o-'])

  zs = reg_line(index1)
  zs.plot(style=['o-'])
```

Which produces the following figure:

[image: Regression Lines with Date Axis]

NOTE: I've added points to the graph to make it clear which values are being drawn on the figure. As you can see, the orange line is straight even though there are no values for some of the days within the range.